# How can I Implement ASButtonNode target using RxSwift

Tags: swift, rx-swift, asyncdisplaykit

I currently have a `UIButton` that uses `rx.tap` function of RxSwift to dismiss a `UIVIewController`

```
button.rx.tap
        .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] in
            self?.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

How can I implement the same function to an `ASButtonNode` object (from AsyncDisplayKit)

I tried with the below code

```
buttonNode.rx.tap
        .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] in
            self?.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

But I get an error saying `Ambiguous reference to member 'tap'`

Or is there any alternative for this.

Comment: Should not you be using some RX extension for ASDK ? something like https://github.com/Hxucaa/RxAsyncDisplayKit

Answer (score 0):

ASButtonNode class is not inherited from UIButton, its child from ASControlNode : ASDisplayNode : NSObject;

So for support this behaviour you must implement similar logic from RXSwift to ASButtonNode, you can find it on [github](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/f29e58003b87016dfd9374031bd3545af659caf8/RxCocoa/iOS/UIButton%2BRx.swift) for UIButton. do similar logic for ASButtonNode and push it on github :) .